# How can I import JS and HTML from a file?

Tags: javascript, html

Example import found in js file
Please adjust it so that the code is saved in the js file
Hello Please Help Example import found in js file Please adjust it so that the code is saved in the js file

```html
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>table</title>
</head>
<script>
  function myim() {
    a.innerHTML = import code in b.js
  }
</script>

<body >
 <div id="a" align="center">
 </div>

<p>
 <input type="button" name="go" id="bn" value="import" onclick="myim()"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

file b.js

```html
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="80" dir="rtl">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;<span lang="en">number</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You probably want to research how to use AJAX

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: charlietfl import code in file js

Comment: That's not code, that's HTML. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You need to request the file and do something with it's content....that's what ajax is used for. html code should be in an html file not a js file

Comment: charlietfl  Please attach an example

Comment: charlietfl Please attach an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` in javascript to request data from the server.
`file.open("GET", "b.js");` can be used to open the file.
`file.responseText` is used to get data from that file.

**Note:**

> Use this code on web server (local or online) to avoid CORS policy in some browsers.

```
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>table</title>
</head>
<script>
  function myim() {
    var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
    file.open("GET", "b.js");
    file.onreadystatechange = function (){
        content = file.responseText;
        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = content;
    }
    file.send(null);
  }
</script>

<body >
    <div id="a" align="center"></div>

    <p><input type="button" name="go" id="bn" value="import" onclick="myim()"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you